# How I can perfomance a GLM with several independent variables

Tags: generalized-linear-model

I need to performa a GLM for several independent variables for a Gaussian family, something like this:

$y$~$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6$

how i can do this?

thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Welcome to CV. Since you’re new here, you may want to take our [tour], which has information for new users. The way that independent variables are handled in GLMs (e.g., logistic regression) is not different from, say, OLS (of course, you have a link function in GLM that *links* systematic (here, independent variables) and random components). Could you tell us more about your problem?

Comment: The exact method will depend on software (and questions about coding are off topic here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly store your data into a dataframe. You can do this as follows

```
dat <- data.frame(y=y,x1=x1,x2=x2,...,x6=x6)
```

Next decide what kind of GLM you want to fit, and also what link function you want to fit.

Then use R code of the form

```
glm(formula, family=familytype(link=linkfunction), data=)
```

So for example

```
model <- glm(y ~x1+x2+x3+x4+x5+x6, family=gaussian(link=identity),data=dat)
```

`data=dat` is optional.

I would recommend searching crossvalidated before asking questions in future. A massive amount of questions on fitting GLM's exist with very well written answers.